# FAIL TypeError: TypedDict does not support instance and class checks in Robot Framework Browser Library

Tags: selenium, browser, robotframework

I am getting following error in Robot Framework Browser library,

```
TypeError: TypedDict does not support instance and class checks

KEYWORD Browser . New Context httpCredentials=${credentials}

Documentation:  Create a new BrowserContext with specified options. See Browser, Context and Page for more information about BrowserContext.
Tags:   BrowserControl, Setter
Start / End / Elapsed:  20210513 09:43:59.248 / 20210513 09:43:59.259 / 00:00:00.011
09:43:59.259 FAIL TypeError: TypedDict does not support instance and class checks
```

My test case is ,

```
* Settings ***  
Library           SeleniumLibrary  
Library           OperatingSystem  
Library         Browser  


*** Test Cases ***
Starting a browser with a page
    New Browser    chromium    headless=false
    New Context    viewport={'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
    New Page       https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html
    Get Title      ==    Browser
```

Comment: You are getting this error when you do what? Please share any code attempt(s) you have.

Comment: I tried to execute below tc* Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem
Library   Browser



*** Variables ***

&{credentials}=    username="xxx"    password="xxx"
${SiteUrl}        xxx

*** Test Cases ***
Successful login
    test1

*** Keywords ***
tes1

    New Browser
    New Context    httpCredentials=${credentials}
    New Page    xxx